a 2D NIM variant with symmetric rules
I have been trying to find which positions are winning or losing positions in following 2D NIM variant.
say balls are lay-ed out in a nxm rectangular way (here 3x4)

o o o o
o o o o
o o o o

but starting position can be any subset of such layout, for example

o   o o
o o o  
o o o o

2 players can take each turn any amount of balls anywhere

horizontally

vertically

diagonally up

diagonally down


so a turn could take (marked x)

o   o o
x o o  
o x o o

giving

o   o o
  o o  
o   o o

Note that linear 1D taking can cross or skip gaps (see comments
@paw88789) where no ball or where a ball is present, so e.g.:

o   o  
o o o  
o o o  

or:

o     o
o o o  
o o   o

could also result after taking next turn.
Q: Which starting positions are losing ones and which starting positions are winning ones?
Perhaps one can limit to n=m nxn or even n=m and n=2^l ... but for general question I suppose balls can be anywhere on a grid.
Just like in original NIM, there is a regular version and a misery version. I guess it does not matter but for now assume regular version: try to make last take (and be the winner).
Also, just like in original NIM, given any losing position, what is algorithm to go to winning position your turn?
Perhaps this is a well known variant ? I must admit then and apologize : not known to me.
I spent a fair amount of time on this question and, for example, it seems positions symmetric to center are losing positions if one counters any take by one symmetric to center.
Also, any losing position has many partners using translation, rotation, and flipping horizontally vertically diagonally ...
But I fear that may only be the beginning of path to mathematical solution ...
I suppose some algebra tag may be appropriate but not sure which one.

Clarifications please:  (1) Can a player take balls across a gap in a line? For instance can a player take all three pieces in the top row of you second diagram? (2) And, if the answer to the above question is 'yes', can a player take balls in a line skipping over some balls. For instance, in your first diagram (with the full rectangle), can a player take the first and third balls in the top row?

(1) and (2) gaps allowed (full or empty), thanks for asking! I adjust or clarify in OP

If you restrict to just taking 2 orthogonally-adjacent balls, this is the game CRAM, which is hard to solve. It's very possible that the freedom of movement here causes some sort of collapse to a simple rule, at least for rectangular boards. Could you share the results of your program/investigation so far?

@MarkS. : the program itself is simple recursion. Looking at 3x3 and 4x4 game one gets the impression, just like with normal NIM, that countering looser take with a similar one, in this case a mirror take, maintains win. So symmetric positions and their equivalents seem to be looser positions. I have never found or extracted an invariant or algorithm like in normal NIM to counter any looser positions. To play 3x3 basically, just like I did as a child for 1357 NIM, one ends up remembering looser positions. Not mathematically impressive :)

I would recommend looking at this game without the diagonal moves first.

The winning positions are those which allow you to take the last move. The losing positions are those which force you to allow your opponent to enter a winning position. You may build the graph of moves by simply enumerating all possible moves. If you can force an odd number of moves then you win, otherwise you lose. You may make the relations and moves as complicated as you like, but this general formula will always work to solve the problem. Simply use a computer to enumerate over all possible moves and solve the problem for that.
There isn't much of a hope to get a better answer, as diagonals and these moves where you may take a line over a gap etc. make everything too messy to lay out in a simple algebraic way.

Thanks ! I did program obvious simple algorithm, even with some tricks to handle rather far way balls on the grid, and some symmetric (but also other) patterns emerge, ... there must be some invariant and the rules are kind of hinting me to some algebra ... which is why I ask expert help here :)

Also: I hesitated using recreational-mathematics tag because for small n the nxn game sure is feasible to play.
